# Статусы ответов в BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth

Использую BLE для подключения к нескольким устройствам. После нескольких подключений, управления устройствами, соединение все время разрывается с кодом 128 (GATT_NO_RESOURCES). Кто подскажет, чем это могло быть вызванно и как бороться? 
Читал что можно выключать-включать bluetooth, но это не приемлемый вариант.
Спасибо!

Comment: мне кажется, что перевключение Bluetooth - это самое оптимальное решение. Знали бы вы с мое, сколько багов и кастомных реализаций каждый производитль вкладывает в свое устройство - согласились бы

Comment: Возможно, но это занимает какое то время, в моем случае это критично(